# Adequate Sets and Well-Formed Formulas

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Quick question: Does every formula defined using an adequate set mean that the formula is a well-formed formula?

Comment: Your question is either imprecise or trivial. What do you mean by “a formula defined using an adequate set”? Presumably you mean “a well-formed formula using only the connectives in the adequate set,” in which case the answer to your question is obvious.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Hello, what I mean is that do adequate sets only define wffs?

Comment: What does “define” mean? Give an example of why you think there is a possibility they *don’t* define a wff.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I don't really have an example! I just wanted to make sure, because then if the set $\left \{\vee ,\wedge , \to  \right \}$ is adequate, then any formula written with this set can be written in conjunctive normal form, which then proves that there exists a row such that if all variables are T, then the formula is T. However, I am not sure whether this is correct either.

Comment: Reread my first comment very slowly. You are confused.

Comment: Asuming that the set $\{ \lor, \land \to \}$ is an *adequate* set of connectives, the string $p \to \land$ is **not** well-formed.